# How to corrupt content database?

Tags: 2010, database

I am working on a solution using which Site Admins can check and repair corrupt DB. I need sample corrupt DB for testing. Any ideas how to corrupt content database?

Comment: Please explain corruption? There are so many ways to have a corrupt db

Comment: Corrupt as in a modified database schema (i.e. columns names, etc.) or as in broken dependencies and orphan records?

Comment: SP2010 already have a health rule with a "fix it" feature in CA for orphaned records (but, do not use it if you have SP1 + june/aug, since it does not care about the recycle bin).

Comment: As you are working on the solution, You might be knowing what kind of corruption it fixes and get a clue :). However, you should not try to modify the SharePoint DBs directly other then using SharePoint API

Comment: Sorry! Missed to add. Corruption in terms of orphaned records.

Comment: Trying to write a solution for a problem you don't have? :P

Comment: :-) I am writing the code on my dev machine which have less number of SP Apps but we have bigger DBs in the prod.

Comment: First time destructive question???

Answer (score 1):

What a great question! I would recommend hitting the server with a high load (eg. automated tool), then restart SQL Server machine.

This will put the Databases in an inconsistent state and need to have integrity checks run on them when it restarts.